# Client's CC double charged when Back is clicked

Tags: php, javascript

I'm trying to eliminate the phenomenon of resending information when
a client press the back button (php).

I'm  using post to post values to a result page when a client hits the
details from result and goes to details page once press back then the
message <<(To display this page, Firefox must send information that will
repeat any action (such as a search or order confirmation) that was
performed earlier.)>> This message appears on Firefox and other major browsers.

What's the simplest method to get rid off that?

Comment: Hi. Please read up on the [post-redirect-get-pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) to solve the issue. Basically, redirect to a GET request once a POST request was successful.

Comment: @Berry - could You please submit this as an answer, so I can accept it? Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read up on the [post-redirect-get-pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) to solve the issue. Basically, redirect to a GET request once a POST request was successful.